# When should spoiler tags stop being used?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

[Is there any story reason for Force users being less acrobatic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/122830/11841)

> It seems strange to me to see spoiler tags for a movie that has been out over three months. It makes questions hard to read.

So my question is:

> Am I able to edit these sorts of spoiler tags out of questions when I see them? It really makes it annoying to read/skim questions and answers when the meaningful content in them are hidden in spoiler tags. Also I am unsure how many people visiting from google will even know to mouseover the tags, does SE have data related to that?

This entire site could be hidden behind spoiler tags at a certain point. It seems 3+ months especially for such a popular movie to consider that... over.

Comment: General discussion of spoiler policy [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers), TFA-specific discussion [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/will-we-ever-clean-up-those-ridiculous-spoiler-free-the-force-awakens-question).

Comment: @randal'thor so basically the concensus has been for multiple months to cleanup the spoiler tags?

Comment: I guess so, but given the sheer number of TFA questions, that's gonna be a lot of work! If you want, you could try suggesting a big cleanup effort, but the idea may be [summarily rejected](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/when-should-we-do-another-tag-cleanup/9211#9211). And we should still keep to the [general principles](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) for spoilers.

Comment: Three months is hardly a long time. It's not even out on DVD yet.

Comment: I've had people choose to edit spoiler tags into a question on a show that ended 10 years ago. (I don't generally mind.) There's been other old material that's happened with.